# Verifying Signatures from other ECC Curves with ecRecover

Tags: signature

My Question is, can I verify a ECDSA Signature from a different ECC Curve like scep128r1 or secp256k1 with the ecRecover function?

If not, are there any good Library's which have implemented this feature?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use ecrecover with curves other than secp256k1.

There's the library [SolCrypto](https://github.com/HarryR/solcrypto) that implements some cryptographic primitives for other supported types like alt-bn128.

The EVM is very simple machine, implementing ECC for standard curves on top of it I'd say is unfeasible due to costs.

The other option is to add them as precompiled contracts. There are several improvement proposals https://eips.ethereum.org/all.